# Употребление различных скобок

Tags: редактура

Если в тексте используются круглые скобки, надо ли выделять внутритекстовые описания-ссылки другими скобками (квадратными)?

Comment: Если описание источника указано в списке лит-ры, допустимо ли внутритекстовую ссылку дать в след. виде: (Иванов, 1980, с. 5), то есть везде запятые?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внутритекстовая ссылка приводится непосредственно в строке после текста, к которому она относится. Она может находиться как в середине, так и в конце предложения.

1. А. П. Александров в своей книге „ Атомная энергетика и научно-технический прогресс “ **(М., 1978. С. 81)** подчеркивает, что...
2. Бердяев с горечью пишет, что "старая Европа изменила своему прошлому, отреклась от него" **(Смысл истории. М., 1990. С. 166)**.

Текст ссылки (библиографическое описание источника) заключается в круглые скобки **()**.
Ссылка оформляется тем же шрифтом, каким набран весть текст.

Пример со скобками в тексте.
*Вполне обоснованное разъяснение диалектики творчества священника Павла Флоренского даёт игумен **Андронник (Трубачёв) (Цит. по: Флоренский П. А. У водоразделов мысли. М., 1990. Т. 2. С. 27).***

[Внутритекстовые ссылки](http://doc-style.ru/SPR/?id=1.19)
[Примеры оформления ссылок](http://lib.sseu.ru/sites/default/files/2017/01/primery_oformleniya_ssylok_v_dissertacii_gost_r_7.0.5-2008_bibliogr.ssylka_0.pdf)

**Дополнение-разъяснение** (после комментария)

*Если описание источника указано в списке лит-ры, допустимо ли внутритекстовую ссылку дать в след. виде: (Иванов, 1980, С. 5)? То есть между фамилией и датой ставить запятую?*

Вы **путаете** внутритекстовые (в круглых скобках) и затекстовые (в квадратных скобках) ссылки. Если вы отправляете читателя к списку литературы, то такая ссылка считается затекстовой.
**Затекстовые ссылки** — это указания на источники цитат с отсылкой к пронумерованному или **алфавитному** списку литературы, помещаемому в конце работы.
При отсутствии нумерации в отсылке указывают сведения, позволяющие идентифицировать объект ссылки: указывают фамилии авторов, при необходимости сведения дополняют указанием года издания и страниц (со строчной буквы); сведения в отсылке разделяют запятой.

В тексте: **[Пахомов, Петрова]**.
В затекстовой ссылке: Пахомов В. И., Петрова Г. П. Логистика. М.: Проспект, 2006. 232 с.

В тексте: **[Бахтин, 2003, с. 18]**.
В затекстовой ссылке: Бахтин М. М. Формальный метод в литературоведении: критическое введение в социальную поэтику. М.: Лабиринт, 2003. 192 c.

Comment: Если описание источника указано в списке лит-ры, допустимо ли внутритекстовую ссылку дать в след. виде: (Иванов, 1980. С. 5)? То есть между фамилией и датой ставить запятую?

Comment: Точнее: (Иванов, 1980, с. 5), то есть везде запятые.